# In Java Hibernate, the get two values from form select in two tables

Tags: java, spring, database, hibernate, select

i stuck on this:

I hava a select form in .jsp. It takes a list from second table items="${categoryList}" . But when i want to save the selection by name then only category_id is updated in table A. I need to have category name in tableA from the list and at the same time category_id in TableA (which works now). But i need name also.

Is there a way to return 2 values from one list in one select?
Extract from jsp

```
category
    <form:select itemLabel="name" itemValue="id"
                 path="category.id" items="${categoryList}"/>
    enter code here
```

Comment: Show your code in Controller and/or Service layer.

Comment: I found solution myself. I will share it soon. Thx